# The "RemoveQroperties" parameter is not supported by the "MSBuild" task

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, msbuild

I was refactoring some of my classes, when all of a sudden I started getting a strange error when trying to build the solution:

> The "MSBuild" task could not be initialized with its input parameters.
>
> The "RemoveQroperties" parameter is not supported by the "MSBuild" task. Verify the parameter exists on the task, and it is a setteable public instance property

**Note:** It *actually* says ***RemoveQroperties***, it is not a typo

Honestly, I have no idea what change of mine has triggered this error, but one of the important ones was this:

I added a new constructor to a base class and its child:

```
public abstract class BaseHashAlgorithm<T> : IHashAlgorithm
{
     protected BaseHashAlgorithm() : this (null) {} //Added this one
     protected BaseHashAlgorithm(ILogger logger)
     {
          this._logger = logger;
          this._hashingAlgorithm = (HashAlgorithm)Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
     }
}

public class MD5HashAlgorithm : BaseHashAlgorithm<MD5CryptoServiceProvider>
{
     public MD5HashAlgorithm() : base() {} //Added this one
     public MD5HashAlgorithm(ILogger logger) : base(logger) {}
}
```

I'm not pretty confident this change is the cause of this error, but I really don't know where else to look.

Snippet of my project file:

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
  <!-- To modify your build process, add your task inside one of the targets below and uncomment it. 
       Other similar extension points exist, see Microsoft.Common.targets.
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  </Target>
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
  </Target>
  -->
```